# Sound device lost after update to 18.10

Tags: sound, output, 18.10

Today I did an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 18.10. 
The update ran without any error message. After the update the sound settings just show "dummy output".

```
$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 7
properties:
    alsa.card = "2"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "10de"
    device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
    device.product.id = "0e1b"
    device.product.name = "GK107 HDMI Audio Controller"
    device.string = "2"
    device.description = "GK107 HDMI Audio Controller"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <off>
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.usb-Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam-02>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 8
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "Trust Webcam"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Trust Webcam Trust Webcam at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.2/sound/card1"
    udev.id = "usb-Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam-02"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "0c45"
    device.vendor.name = "Microdia"
    device.product.id = "6340"
    device.product.name = "Camera"
    device.serial = "Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam"
    device.form_factor = "webcam"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "Camera"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
profiles:
    input:analog-mono: Analog Mono Input (priority 7, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <input:analog-mono>
sources:
    alsa_input.usb-Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam_Trust_Webcam-02.analog-mono/#0: Camera Analog Mono
ports:
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
```

lspci

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

destailed lspci

```
$ sudo lspci -nnk |  grep -A2 Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
  Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [103c:1905]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio 
Controller [10de:0e1b] (rev a1)
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GK107 HDMI Audio Controller [103c:094b]
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

[Screenshot Sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yfuk.png)
[Screenshot Additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T765s.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. Found out on [another site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1797714) that my issue was solved by uninstalling timidity. After a reboot I have sound again.

Comment: That solved the problem for me without even having to reboot. Just run `sudo apt-get remove timidity` and sound started to play immediately

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, and dns lookup as well (almost having no internet connection at all, it switches off in a random-long very first minutes after booting, quite annoying situation)